# linux_mint17.3, python2.7, which pillow

Tags: python, linux

linux `python` and `pillow`:

I just upgraded to `mint 17.3`. The docs say this is an `Ubuntu14.04` Kernel. 
I wish to run python and the python imaging libarary => pillow.

When I run > python < (command line) i get as follows;

```
grumpy@grumpy-desktop ~ $ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I am assuming that `python2.7.6` is the default module used. Within usr/
lib/ python2.6, python2.7, python3 and python3.4 all exist. 
However; I have been unable to get the version of PIL or Pillow being used.
PIL exist in `usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL`, along with 
`~/Pillow2.3.0.eggs-info` (not much help here.)

The docs indicate that Linux mint17.3, with an Umbuntu14.04 Kurnel and
python2.7, that Pillow2.3.0 would be most compatable.

So the question is; How to install Pillow2.3.0, with ALL THE MODULES,
for full functionality. I wish to include in scripts;

```
Image.putpixel(xy, value)

Image.putdata(data, scale=1.0, offset=0.0)
```

At present when I run the above I get;

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'putdata' (or 'putpixel')
```

or, if needed;
How to change python version used, so to install another Pillow version
with full functionality.
Thanks for the input guys.

Comment: You seem confused.  `putpixel` and `putdata` are methods of the `Image` *class*, not functions in the `Image` module.  So I'm not sure if there's an install version problem at all or not.  (You can `import PIL`; `print(PIL.PILLOW_VERSION)` to check what pillow version you're importing.)